# Update DB with variables SQLite AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sqlite

I try to update my DB using SQLite, in AngularJS. But I want to update with variable, and it did not works.

Code:

```
if (window.cordova && window.SQLitePlugin) {
      var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: "my.db", location: 1 }); //device
    }else{
      var db = window.openDatabase("my.db", '1', 'my', 5 * 1024 * 1024); // browser


}

var siret1=data["siret"]
    console.log(siret1);

    var query1 = "UPDATE User SET siret = \'siret1\' " ;
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query1).then(function(res) {
            console.log("ok update");

        }, function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            console.log("not ok update");
        });
```

I tried with '. .' "" \' and may things, but nothing works.

The plugin: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/

Cheers

Comment: You can insert variable parts into strings by using concatenation: `"I'm " + age + " years old!"`

Comment: I know, but how can I can set siret from by table with my var siret1 ? var query1 = "UPDATE User SET siret = HEREMYVAR "

Comment: `query1` is a string. Build the string like shown above. How do you think these cases are different?

Comment: Still a problem. I cannot insert text with spaces (ie : "My Var") : SQLError {code: 5, message: "could not prepare statement (1 near "Var": syntax error)"}

Comment: Inspect the resulting query string. If it's not valid SQL, change the generating code so that it produces valid SQL.

Comment: I inspect the resulting query string There is a problem when a insert string like " I'm ready" because of the '